# Boot Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS with no boot-loader

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, boot-loader

I have Ubuntu installed on the hard drive next to Windows. On the end of the installation, I had an error and Grub was skipped.

How can I boot this system with no bootloader?

Maybe we have some Boot CD detecting all installations in the system or something?

Comment: Google is trying to tell me that I need to install boot-loader, but maybe I can do this on USB or use some different solution like Grub alternative?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions (without installing GRUB to MBR):

1. Create a bootable USB with Live Ubuntu.
2. Boot into Live Ubuntu.
3. Mount `root(/)` partition that contains your previous Ubuntu installation in the HDD.
4. Open `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` and find necessary menu entry `menuentry { ... }` structure (previous installation in the HDD).
5. Paste in `/etc/grub/grub.d/40_custom` file of the Live Ubuntu your `menuentry` structure (previous item).
6. Run `sudo update-grub` for update GBUR changes.
7. Reboot.

Now you will be able to see new entry of GRUB menu that contains your installation from HDD. Just choose and boot. Hope it helps.

---

Restore GRUB

If you want restore GRUB and allow boot Windows too, see the [next answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/145253) from Ask Ubuntu portal.

Comment: /etc/grub/grub.cfg does not exist in my Ubuntu files, I had an error on the end of the installation

Comment: I have grug.cnf from another ubuntu I will try to copy this one but I see that we have specified files or something in the config...

menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-45-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-45-generic-recovery-0943a79d-fe9b-4afa-9532-8285f969536c'